# make a if statement run only when submit button is clicked

Tags: php, post

Here i have a form and some php code to run only when submit button is clicked.But the "IF" block run as soon as the page reloads.As if the $_POST array is not empty.I can try with a single element,like `!empty($_POST['name'])`.But i want to test on universal $_POST array.How can i do it?

```
<?php 
require_once 'input.php';

 if(Input::exists()){
  print_r($_POST);
  $arr=array('ball');
  echo $arr[0];
}
?>

<form action='' method='POST'>
   name:<input type='text' name='name' ></br>
   <input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
```

input.php file:

```
  class Input{
     public static function exists($type='post'){
         switch($type){

           case 'post':
               return (!empty($_POST))?true:false;
               break;
            default:
               return (!empty($_GET))?true:false;
               brek;

         }
     }
  }
```

Comment: There's a typo in the `default` case; you wrote `brek;`.

Comment: Also, what does `print_r($_POST);` return on page load?

Comment: if you want a universal test, then `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {... }`. that'll be true no matter what got submitted bythe client.

Comment: @StuartWagner it retruns array([name]=>'')

Comment: Apart from the typo there's no reason why that code won't work... you're not, by any chance, just reloading the page each time?

Comment: what i am trying to ask is ,in my code the if block get accessed no matter what i clicked the submit button or not ! i want it to get accessed only when the submit button is clicked. REQUEST_METHOD seems working.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the Input class? Just do this:

```
if ($_POST['name']) {
    print_r($_POST);
    $arr=array('ball');
    echo $arr[0];
}
```

Comment: i could ,but i don't want to check on a single element as there can be multiple elements in the form.

Comment: So are you just trying to make sure one form is posted? Another option is to have a hidden field with a value, then when the form is posted check this hidden field has been posted.

Comment: Having multiple elements in the form does not change anything. This solution will still work. If you're trying to make sure *all* the fields contain something, simply checking for the existence of the entire `$_POST` array wouldn't really help you any more than this will. For that, you would need to write a bigger `if` statement, or better yet, `if` statements for each field that generate reasonable errors to be passed back to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add a name to your submit button

> `<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>
>   if(isset($_POST['submit']))
>   {
>       php code goes here this will only run when submit btn has been clicked
>   }`

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want a form to submit data to itself omit the `action` attribute
2. The input class is incredibly overkill, but I suppose if you want to use it then we can make it work.

Change the `Input` class to look something like this...

```
class Input {
        public static function exists($type='post') {
             if ($type == 'post' && count($_POST) > 0)
                    return true;
             else if ($type == 'get' && count($_GET) > 0)
                    return true;
        }
  }
```

I frankly hate switch statements and this should work just fine.  Once again, I think the `Input` class is overkill.